# validating a string with RegEx

Tags: java, regex, validation, textfield

I am trying to validate a RegEx string in Java but i cant get it to work properly. I am attempting to make sure the the following string "AB10XY" is always contained with the textField when performing a search.

I have the following line of code which ensures that AB and XY are in the textField but not the number:

```
boolean checkChar = ((textField.getText().contains("AB")) && (textField.getText().contains("XY")));
```

I would prefer to have something like :

```
boolean checkChar = ((textField.getText().contains("AB[\\d]{2}XY")));
```

Comment: *""AB10XY" is always contained with the textField when performing a search."*  Wouldn't it be simpler for you **&** the user to make that text field uneditable?

Comment: Were you intending to answer my question, or just ignore it?  Note that there are probably better ways to go about this than using a RegEx, but until I have more details of the problem, it is hard to narrow them down.

Comment: Hi Sorry for the delay. i used one of the solutions listed below to fix the issue except i added brackets to the RegEx formula to say ".*[AB[\\d]{2}XY].*" it works perfectly so far. I am using this solution to check if "AB12XY" is in a path. eg : C:\Users\user\Documents\Handbacks\AB12XYmmmd (mmm=month, d=day)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way

```
boolean checkChar = ((textField.getText().matches(".*?AB[\\d]{2}XY.*")));
```

Comment: @Anirudh true, but for some reason OP used it (maybe it will be expanded in real code)

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the number isn't alway 10, so you should use something like this:

```
boolean checkChar = textField.getText().matches(".*AB[\\d]{2}XY.*");
```

Answer (score 0):

Contains method doesn't support regex..You can use [matches](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29) method

```
 textField.getText().matches(".*AB\\d{2}XY.*");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use package `java.util.regex` to handle RegEx

```
boolean checkChar = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("AB[\\d]{2}XY")
        .matcher(textField.getText()).find();
```